# O width da table do html não aumenta conforme pedido para assinatura do outlook

Tags: html, css

Preciso fazer uma assinatura em html e css para outlook e precisa ter um width de no maximo 320px  para ajuste em celulares, fiz desse modo mas os width que peço não ficam, alguém pode me ajudar, nunca usei tabela então posso ter feito algo errado. Código abaixo junto com a execução

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="320">
<tbody  width="320">
<tr width="320">

<td rowspan="6" width="136" height="150"><a href="http://politicadascidades.com.br/"><img width="136" height="136" src="http://politicadascidades.com.br/img/assinaturas/assinatura-iloveimg-resized.jpg" alt="" align="top" /></a></td>

</tr>

<tr width="320">
<td width="183">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr width="320">
 <td width="183"><span width="183" id="titulo" style="font-size: 25px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica">&nbsp;&nbsp;Fabiana Correa</span></td>
</tr>

<tr width="320">
 <td><span id="subtitulo" style="color:grey; font-size: 19px;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Editora</span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="183"><span style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;19 <span style="font-size: 26px;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica">99432-4813</span></span></td>
</tr>

<tr width="320">
<td width="183">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr width="320">
<td width="183">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://politicadascidades.com.br/"><img src="http://politicadascidades.com.br/img/assinaturas/icone-browser.png" height="20" align="bottom"></a>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.facebook.com/politicadascidades"><img src="http://politicadascidades.com.br/img/assinaturas/icone-face.png" alt="" height="20" align="bottom" /></a>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.instagram.com/politicadascidades/"><img src="http://politicadascidades.com.br/img/assinaturas/icone-insta.png" alt="" height="20" align="bottom" /></a>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://twitter.com/politicacidades"><img src="http://politicadascidades.com.br/img/assinaturas/icone-twitter.png" alt="" height="20" align="bottom" /></a>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPH6zKPor8s8VRjeruSUnrw"><img src="http://politicadascidades.com.br/img/assinaturas/icone-youtube.png" alt="" height="20" align="bottom" /></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Não seria o caso de diminuir a fonte então? Se tu colocar o font size em 20px fica como tu quer...

Answer (score 0):

Para que ele mantenha a proporção correta no mobile, você precisa fixar o header, você pode fazer isto inserindo a meta tag abaixo:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui galera, fiz uma mesclagem entre as colunas e linhas e os icones cada um coloquei em uma td segue o code,

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="320" height="115">
 <tr width="136">
  <td rowspan="4">
   <a href="http://politicadascidades.com.br/">
   <img width="136" height="115" src="http://politicadascidades.com.br/img/assinaturas/assinatura-iloveimg-resize.jpg" alt="" align="center" />
   </a>
  </td>
  <td colspan="5" width="183" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;">
   <span width="183" id="titulo" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica;">Fabiana Correa</span>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="5" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;">
   <span id="subtitulo" style="color:gray;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica;" color="gray">Editora</span>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="5" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;">
   <span style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica; font-size: 10px;">19</span>
   <span style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica">99432-4813</span> 
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;"><a href="http://politicadascidades.com.br/"><img src="http://politicadascidades.com.br/img/assinaturas/icone-browser.png" height="17" width="17" align="center"></a></td>
  <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/politicadascidades"><img src="http://politicadascidades.com.br/img/assinaturas/icone-face.png" alt="" height="17" width="17" align="center" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="https://www.instagram.com/politicadascidades/"><img src="http://politicadascidades.com.br/img/assinaturas/icone-insta.png" alt="" height="17" width="17" align="center" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="https://twitter.com/politicacidades"><img src="http://politicadascidades.com.br/img/assinaturas/icone-twitter.png" alt="" height="17" width="17" align="center" /></a></td>
  <td><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPH6zKPor8s8VRjeruSUnrw"><img src="http://politicadascidades.com.br/img/assinaturas/icone-youtube.png" alt="" height="17" width="17" align="center" /></a></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```